# Difference between groupby and pivot_table for pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I just started learning Pandas and was wondering if there is any difference between `groupby` and `pivot_table` functions. Can anyone help me understand the difference between them?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Both `pivot_table` and `groupby` are used to aggregate your dataframe. The difference is only with regard to the shape of the result.

Using `pd.pivot_table(df, index=["a"], columns=["b"], values=["c"], aggfunc=np.sum)` a table is created where `a` is on the row axis, `b` is on the column axis, and the values are the sum of `c`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,2,3,1,2,3], "b":[1,1,1,2,2,2], "c":np.random.rand(6)})
pd.pivot_table(df, index=["a"], columns=["b"], values=["c"], aggfunc=np.sum)

b         1         2
a                    
1  0.528470  0.484766
2  0.187277  0.144326
3  0.866832  0.650100
```

Using `groupby`, the dimensions given are placed into columns, and rows are created for each combination of those dimensions.

In this example, we create a series of the sum of values `c`, grouped by all unique combinations of `a` and `b`.

```
df.groupby(['a','b'])['c'].sum()

a  b
1  1    0.528470
   2    0.484766
2  1    0.187277
   2    0.144326
3  1    0.866832
   2    0.650100
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

A similar usage of `groupby` is if we omit the `['c']`. In this case, it creates a dataframe (not a series) of the sums of all remaining columns grouped by unique values of `a` and `b`.

```
print df.groupby(["a","b"]).sum()
            c
a b          
1 1  0.528470
  2  0.484766
2 1  0.187277
  2  0.144326
3 1  0.866832
  2  0.650100
```

Answer (score 21):

`groupby` and `pivot_table` are related as follows (in fact, under the hood `pivot_table` is defined using `groupby`)<sup>1</sup>:

- **pivot_table = groupby + unstack**
- **groupby = pivot_table + stack**

In particular, if `columns` parameter of `pivot_table()` is not used, then `groupby()` and `pivot_table()` both produce the same result (if the same aggregator function is used).

```py
# sample
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,1,2,2,2], "b": [1,1,2,2,3,3], "c": [0,0.5,1,1,2,2]})

# example
gb = df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c']].sum()
pt = df.pivot_table(index=['a','b'], values=['c'], aggfunc='sum')

# equality test
gb.equals(pt)   # True <--- no `columns=` kwarg, no `unstack()`
```

---

If you're familiar with Microsoft Excel, both `pivot_table` and `groupby` behave like the PivotTable functionality in Excel:

- `groupby`: `by` kwarg (i.e. grouper column) corresponds to ROWS, the columns being aggregated correspond to VALUES and the groupby methods (`mean()`, `sum()` etc.) correspond to the functions you select in Value Field Settings.
- `pivot_table`: `values` kwarg corresponds to VALUES, `index` corresponds to ROWS, `columns` corresponds to COLUMNS and `aggfunc` corresponds to the function you select in Value Field Settings.

In pandas, just like in Excel, `groupby` results in a long stacked table, while `pivot_table` results in a wide table. If you unstack the long table from `groupby`, you get the same result as `pivot_table`.

---

<sup>1</sup> In general, if we check the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py), `pivot_table()` internally calls `__internal_pivot_table()`. This function creates a single flat list out of index and columns and calls `groupby()` with this list as the grouper. Then after aggregation, calls `unstack()` on the list of columns.

If columns are never passed, there is nothing to unstack on, so `groupby` and `pivot_table` trivially produce the same output.

A demonstration of this connection is:

```py
gb = (
    df
    .groupby(['a','b'])[['c']].sum()
    .unstack(['b'])
)
pt = df.pivot_table(index=['a'], columns=['b'], values=['c'], aggfunc='sum')

gb.equals(pt)   # True <--- they produce the same output
```

As `stack()` is the inverse operation of `unstack()`, the following holds True as well:

```py
pt = df.pivot_table(index=['a'], columns=['b'], values=['c'], aggfunc='sum').stack(['b'])
gb = df.groupby(['a','b'])[['c']].sum()
pt.equals(gb)   # True  <--- they produce the same output
```

In conclusion, depending on the use case, one is more convenient than the other but they can both be used instead of the other and after correctly applying `stack()`/`unstack()`, both will result in the same output.

However, there's a performance difference between the two methods. In short, `pivot_table()` is slower than `groupby().agg().unstack()`. You can [read more about it from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74048672/19123103).

Comment: understand that the answer was added after the original one was accepted (and still a good answer) but this one explains *why* there is a difference between the two AND how they are connected (through `stack`). Great answer

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that `groupby` is literally in the `pivot_table`'s [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.1/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py) so this answer is not only the most intuitive but also, i'd say, the one with highest fidelity

Answer (score 13):

It's more appropriate to use `.pivot_table()` instead of `.groupby()` when you need to show aggregates with both rows and column labels.

`.pivot_table()` makes it easy to create row and column labels at the same time and is preferable, even though you can get similar results using `.groupby()` with few extra steps.

Answer (score 7):

The `pivot_table` is a kind of two-dimensional `groupby` where you group by two variables (columns) and one variable ends up in the index and another in the columns.

#### [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

[image]

#### [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

[image: pivot_table]