# Pandas performance: pivot_table vs groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I am struggling with performance of `pivot_table` versus `groupby`

On one hand I have:

```
%time df.groupby(['INDEX', 'COLUMN']).agg({'VALUE':['sum','size']}).unstack(level='COLUMN')
CPU times: user 2.28 s, sys: 29.8 ms, total: 2.31 s
Wall time: 2.36 s
```

On the other hand I get:

```
%time pd.pivot_table(df, index='INDEX', columns='COLUMN', values='VALUE', aggfunc=[len, np.sum], fill_value=0)
CPU times: user 1min 51s, sys: 1.57 s, total: 1min 53s
Wall time: 1min 54s
```

These are essentially the same things but I get like 60x performance difference. Why is that?

There are 800k rows with about 400k unique `INDEX` and `COLUMN` has 16 unique values in my sample.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** `pivot_table` loops over `aggfunc` no matter what's passed to it while `groupby` checks if cython-optimized implementation is available first and loops if not.

---

If we peek into the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/reshape/pivot.py#L55-L109) of `pivot_table()`, the way it is implemented is that, when you pass a list of aggregator functions a.k.a. aggfuncs to it, for each `func()` in the list, `groupby().func().unstack()` is called and the resulting list of dataframes are concatenated later on. Meanwhile, [`groupby().agg()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/87cfe4e38bafe7300a6003a1d18bd80f3f77c763/pandas/core/apply.py#L320) tries to first call cython-optimized methods and use loop as a last resort.

So if the functions in aggfuncs are all cython-optimized such as `'sum'` or `'size'`, `groupby().agg()` will perform as many times faster than `pivot_table()` as the number of functions in aggfuncs. In particular, for a single aggregator function, they will perform about the same (although, I imagine `pivot_table()` will still be slightly slower since it has a larger overhead).

However, if the list of functions are not cython-optimized, then since both calls each function in a loop, they will perform about the same. N.B. `groupby().agg().unstack()` makes a call to `unstack()` only once while `pivot_table()` makes the call `len(aggfuncs)` number of times; so naturally, `pivot_table()` will also be slightly slower.

A demonstration of this in code is as follows:

##### Setup:

```py
def groupby_unstack(funcs):
    return df.groupby(['INDEX', 'COLUMN'])['VALUE'].agg(funcs).unstack(level='COLUMN', fill_value=0)

def pivot_table_(funcs):
    return df.pivot_table(index='INDEX', columns='COLUMN', values='VALUE', aggfunc=funcs, fill_value=0)

def get_df(k):
    return pd.DataFrame({'INDEX': np.random.default_rng().choice(k // 2, size=k), 
                         'COLUMN': np.random.default_rng().choice(16, size=k), 
                         'VALUE': np.random.rand(k).round(2)})
```

##### Cython-optimized functions

As can be seen from the below benchmarks, the gap between the performance of `groupby().agg().unstack()` and `pivot_table()` increases as the number of aggregator functions increase. For a single aggregator function, they perform about the same but for two functions, `pivot_table()` is about twice as slow and for three functions, it is about 3 times as slow etc.

```py
df = get_df(800_000)

cython_funcs1 = ['sum', 'size']

%timeit groupby_unstack(cython_funcs1)
# 1.41 s ± 35.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pivot_table_(cython_funcs1)
# 3.51 s ± 263 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


cython_funcs2 = ['sum', 'size', 'mean']

%timeit groupby_unstack(cython_funcs2)
# 1.63 s ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pivot_table_(cython_funcs2)
# 5.08 s ± 57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


cython_funcs3 = ['median']

%timeit groupby_unstack(cython_funcs3)
# 1.17 s ± 92.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pivot_table_(cython_funcs3)
# 1.84 s ± 70.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

##### Non-cython-optimized functions

For non-cython optimized functions, `groupby().agg().unstack()` and `pivot_table()` perform about the same even for multiple aggregator functions because both loop over the list of functions under the hood.

```py
df = get_df(80_000)

funcs = [lambda x: list(x.mode()), lambda x: x.nunique()**2]

%timeit groupby_unstack(funcs)
# 26.6 s ± 5.99 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pivot_table_(funcs)
# 27.2 s ± 6.46 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```