# Convert multi-year time series into a single year averaged time series using pandas

Tags: python, timestamp, time-series, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame (df) with columns named date, Year, Month, Day, Hour and Energy. It is multiyear Time Series which I want to convert into a averaged single year time series with (8760 points i.e 365 * 24 points) where the column Energy_Mean is averaged out value.

df is

```
date           Year  Month  Day  Hour       Energy
1/1/1999 0:00  1999   Jan    1     1        45.0     
1/1/1999 1:00  1999   Jan    1     2        73.5     
1/1/1999 2:00  1999   Jan    1     3        82.4     
1/1/1999 3:00  1999   Jan    1     4        90.0     
1/1/1999 4:00  1999   Jan    1     5        72.2
.
.
.
12/31/1999 23:00  1999 Dec  12    24       77.0
.
.
.
12/31/2019 23:00  2019 Dec  12    24       84.3
```

Task is to convert it into an averaged form as shown below:

```
Month  Day  Hour      Energy_Mean
Jan    1     1        22.45     
Jan    1     2        73.5     
Jan    1     3        57.4     
Jan    1     4        88.0     
Jan    1     5        33.2
.
.
.
Dec    31    24       77.0
```

Trying to figure out whether **pivot_table** or **groupby** is a better method of pandas to use to convert time series into 8760 count data frame. Additionally, I want the output to be sorted by months NOT alphabetically. Like Jan, Feb, March, April NOT April, August..

My Code is:

```
p50_8760 = df.groupby(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour'])['Energy'].mean()
df_p50_8760 = p50_8760.to_frame()
```

The output file does not have column names or the data points count of 8760 data points.

Answer (score 0):

According to the response in this SO question [Pandas: group by and Pivot table difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702815/pandas-group-by-and-pivot-table-difference) *pivot_table* and *groupby* might be both equally well suited as they only differ in the shape of the result.
So pick that one that you find easier to work with.

For my example I will use a pivot_table.

In order to sort by a Months' index instead of alphabetically by name, I add an additional column 'Month_ind'. You could do the mapping by hand, of course. Because we already have a datetime column present, I chose to let Pandas do this step.

The numerical column 'Month_ind' can then be used to sort in the end:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data/multi_year_ts.csv')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) # convert column to datetime

df['Month_ind'] = df['date'].map(lambda e: e.month)

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Month_ind', 'Day', 'Hour'], columns=['Year'], values=['Energy'])

print(pivot.sort_values('Month_ind'))
```

**Result:**

```
                   Energy                  
Year                 1999  2005  2007  2019
Month_ind Day Hour                         
1         1   1      45.0  60.4  55.2   NaN
              2      73.5   NaN   NaN   NaN
              3      82.4   NaN   NaN   NaN
              4      90.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
              5      72.2   NaN   NaN   NaN
12        12  24     77.0   NaN   NaN  84.3
```

Note that the values are not correct (and mostly `NaN`) as I only had a very small test sample.

To get the mean value for a specific Hour on a given date over all years, transpose the pivot first:

```py
print(pivot.T.mean())
```

**Final Result:**

```
Month_ind  Day  Hour
1          1    1       53.533333
                2       73.500000
                3       82.400000
                4       90.000000
                5       72.200000
12         12   24      80.650000
dtype: float64
```