# Replacing a pivot with a lazy groupby operation

Tags: python-polars

I'm pivoting a rather large dataframe of shape `(10_000_000, 678)` into one of approx. shape `(770_000, 8_789)` to create a dataset for an ML algorithm. It's a relatively slow operation taking about half an hour on a high-ram cluster I am using, and I'm wondering if there is a way to speed it up. Here is a minimum example, with a larger one below:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

data = {
    "id": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    "rank": [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], # rank is always repeating 1-3 (or 0-12 in large example)
    "A": np.random.random((9)),
    "B": np.random.random((9)),
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
df_pivot = df.pivot(values=["A", "B"], index="id", columns="rank")

# Now rename columns, since they are currently:
# df_pivot.columns
# ['id', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3']
ranks = [1,2,3]
renamed_columns = df_pivot.columns[:1]
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    for rank in ranks:
        renamed_columns.append(f"{col}_{rank}")
df_pivot.columns = renamed_columns
```

```
# df_pivot
shape: (3, 7)
┌─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ A_1      ┆ A_2      ┆ A_3      ┆ B_1      ┆ B_2      ┆ B_3      │
│ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0.867957 ┆ 0.854234 ┆ 0.408062 ┆ 0.076254 ┆ 0.899092 ┆ 0.059019 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 0.642296 ┆ 0.670476 ┆ 0.480494 ┆ 0.4254   ┆ 0.536173 ┆ 0.492312 │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3   ┆ 0.778481 ┆ 0.151697 ┆ 0.330138 ┆ 0.6661   ┆ 0.4086   ┆ 0.992057 │
└─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

The [polars pivot code states](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/8bc22e054c9bf7b8288a61ea8e54fd267d092f95/polars/polars-lazy/src/frame/pivot.rs#L1) that in a comment:

> Polars lazy does not implement a pivot because it is impossible to know the schema without materializing the whole dataset. This makes a pivot quite a terrible operation for performant workflows. An optimization can never be pushed down passed a pivot.

And in the [groupby.pivot](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/8bc22e054c9bf7b8288a61ea8e54fd267d092f95/polars/polars-core/src/frame/groupby/pivot.rs#L43) code:

> Polars'/arrow memory is not ideal for transposing operations like pivots. If you have a relatively large table, consider using a groupby over a pivot.

Some questions:

- Is it possible to replace the above pivot example by a (preferably lazy) combination of groupby and something else? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56676656/1018861) about pandas suggests an equivalency of groupby + "unstack" with pivot. Polars does not implement an unstack function, afaik.
- Is the above suggestion more performant than the current pivot implementation? (See the larger example below).
- I actually *do* know the schema ahead-of-schedule, since in my situation `rank` is a known series ([1, 2, 3] in the example). If implemented, would a lazy pivot where one can supply the schema be more performant than the eager one?
- Should I be implementing it differently?

```py
# Much larger example, but with 10_000 rows instead of 10_000_000
# 10_000 runs in 3 seconds, 100_000 runs in 40 seconds (M1 macbook)

from string import ascii_lowercase
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

ranks = np.arange(13)
N_ROWS = 10_000 # this could be ~10_000_000

df = (pl.DataFrame({"ID": np.arange(N_ROWS)})).join(
    pl.DataFrame({"rank": ranks}), how="cross"
)

# create 26**2 dummy column names
column_names = []
for letter1 in ascii_lowercase:
    for letter2 in ascii_lowercase:
        column_names.append(letter1 + letter2)

# stack frames to create: ID, ranks, aa, ab, ..., zz
df = df.hstack(
    pl.DataFrame({letter: np.random.random(len(df)) for letter in column_names})
    )


df_pivot = df.pivot(values=df.columns[2:], index="ID", columns="rank")

renamed_columns = df_pivot.columns[:1]
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    for rank in ranks:
        renamed_columns.append(f"{col}_{rank}")
df_pivot.columns = renamed_columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a non-lazy solution that brings your wall-clock on the much larger example with `N_ROWS = 1_000_000` from over 7 minutes to around ... **10 seconds**?

### The Algorithm

> I actually do know the schema ahead-of-schedule, since in my situation rank is a known series ([1, 2, 3] in the example). If implemented, would a lazy pivot where one can supply the schema be more performant than the eager one?

We're going to take advantage of the structure of the data.  We'll re-sort the data strategically, and use `slice` on each series.  (Slices are nearly free.)

I've also added an `ID` column with dtype `Int64` so that we can use `frame_equal` to compare the results of this algorithm to the output of the `pivot` code from the example.

Note that the algorithm is not in Lazy mode.

```py
ser_slices = [
    s.slice(rank * N_ROWS, N_ROWS).alias(s.name + "_" + str(rank))
    for s in df.sort(["rank", "ID"])[:, 2:]
    for rank in range(0, 13)
]

result = (
    pl.DataFrame(ser_slices)
    .with_row_count('ID')
    .with_column(
        pl.col('ID').cast(pl.Int64)
    )
)
```

### Performance Comparison

Let's compare the performance and output of the algorithm above with the pivot code in your example.

We'll use your larger example with `N_ROWS = 1_000_000`.

##### The Algorithm Above (Slices in Eager Mode)

If you watch the performance of your CPU on this algorithm (e.g., in `top` on Linux), you'll notice that the algorithm runs heavily in parallel.

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
ser_slices = [
    s.slice(rank * N_ROWS, N_ROWS).alias(s.name + "_" + str(rank))
    for s in df.sort(["rank", "ID"])[:, 2:]
    for rank in range(0, 13)
]

result = (
    pl.DataFrame(ser_slices)
    .with_row_count('ID')
    .with_column(
        pl.col('ID').cast(pl.Int64)
    )
)
result
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (1000000, 8789)
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ ID     ┆ aa_0     ┆ aa_1     ┆ aa_2     ┆ ... ┆ zz_9     ┆ zz_10    ┆ zz_11    ┆ zz_12    │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆     ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆     ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0.702774 ┆ 0.250239 ┆ 0.023121 ┆ ... ┆ 0.348179 ┆ 0.530304 ┆ 0.380147 ┆ 0.194915 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 0.184479 ┆ 0.562245 ┆ 0.038145 ┆ ... ┆ 0.575752 ┆ 0.254793 ┆ 0.126996 ┆ 0.557823 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 0.432553 ┆ 0.111145 ┆ 0.937674 ┆ ... ┆ 0.493157 ┆ 0.843966 ┆ 0.6257   ┆ 0.044151 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 0.607535 ┆ 0.389257 ┆ 0.864887 ┆ ... ┆ 0.765563 ┆ 0.312805 ┆ 0.085054 ┆ 0.4972   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ... ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999996 ┆ 0.101384 ┆ 0.918382 ┆ 0.024    ┆ ... ┆ 0.643435 ┆ 0.905557 ┆ 0.8266   ┆ 0.460866 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999997 ┆ 0.164607 ┆ 0.766515 ┆ 0.565382 ┆ ... ┆ 0.493534 ┆ 0.595359 ┆ 0.601306 ┆ 0.637546 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999998 ┆ 0.213503 ┆ 0.874676 ┆ 0.165461 ┆ ... ┆ 0.676855 ┆ 0.730082 ┆ 0.9647   ┆ 0.710811 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999999 ┆ 0.246028 ┆ 0.963617 ┆ 0.065186 ┆ ... ┆ 0.1091   ┆ 0.913634 ┆ 0.425842 ┆ 0.715304 │
└────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
10.33561857099994
```

Roughly 10 seconds.  Not bad.

##### Pivot (from the example code)

If you watch your CPU monitor, you'll notice that the `pivot` code is largely single-threaded.

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
df_pivot = df.pivot(values=df.columns[2:], index="ID", columns="rank")

renamed_columns = df_pivot.columns[:1]
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    for rank in ranks:
        renamed_columns.append(f"{col}_{rank}")
df_pivot.columns = renamed_columns
df_pivot
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (1000000, 8789)
┌────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ ID     ┆ aa_0     ┆ aa_1     ┆ aa_2     ┆ ... ┆ zz_9     ┆ zz_10    ┆ zz_11    ┆ zz_12    │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆     ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆     ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0.702774 ┆ 0.250239 ┆ 0.023121 ┆ ... ┆ 0.348179 ┆ 0.530304 ┆ 0.380147 ┆ 0.194915 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 0.184479 ┆ 0.562245 ┆ 0.038145 ┆ ... ┆ 0.575752 ┆ 0.254793 ┆ 0.126996 ┆ 0.557823 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 0.432553 ┆ 0.111145 ┆ 0.937674 ┆ ... ┆ 0.493157 ┆ 0.843966 ┆ 0.6257   ┆ 0.044151 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 0.607535 ┆ 0.389257 ┆ 0.864887 ┆ ... ┆ 0.765563 ┆ 0.312805 ┆ 0.085054 ┆ 0.4972   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ... ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999996 ┆ 0.101384 ┆ 0.918382 ┆ 0.024    ┆ ... ┆ 0.643435 ┆ 0.905557 ┆ 0.8266   ┆ 0.460866 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999997 ┆ 0.164607 ┆ 0.766515 ┆ 0.565382 ┆ ... ┆ 0.493534 ┆ 0.595359 ┆ 0.601306 ┆ 0.637546 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999998 ┆ 0.213503 ┆ 0.874676 ┆ 0.165461 ┆ ... ┆ 0.676855 ┆ 0.730082 ┆ 0.9647   ┆ 0.710811 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 999999 ┆ 0.246028 ┆ 0.963617 ┆ 0.065186 ┆ ... ┆ 0.1091   ┆ 0.913634 ┆ 0.425842 ┆ 0.715304 │
└────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
442.1277434679996
```

Over 7 minutes.  (Given that, I didn't bother to time the two with `N_ROWS = 10_000_000`)

##### Comparison of the output

Do they produce the same result?

```
>>> result.frame_equal(df_pivot)
True
```

Comment: I should have noted: I assumed from the example that there is data for each ID/rank combination.  If not, we’ll need to modify the algorithm.

Comment: Nailed it! This was really clear and informative. And much, much faster!