# How do I index by a column and aggregate with another in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following info in a dataframe in python:

From that dataframe, I require another dataframe that summarizes the information of all the students per state per age.

In other words, instead of having one entry per student (with their age and state) I'd like to have a data frame with the rows as the states and the columns as the ages.

[Initial Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8cca.png)

| Student | State | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | California | 13 |
| 2 | California | 14 |
| 3 | Colorado | 12 |
| 4 | Colorado | 11 |
| 5 | Colorado | 12 |
| 6 | Colorado | 10 |
| 7 | Colorado | 13 |
| 8 | Colorado | 12 |
| 9 | Colorado | 13 |
| 10 | Colorado | 11 |
| 11 | Florida | 10 |
| 12 | Florida | 11 |
| 13 | Texas | 11 |
| 14 | Texas | 9 |
| 15 | Texas | 12 |
| 16 | Texas | 10 |

This is what I am expecting

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSS5c.png)

| State | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| California | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Colorado | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 0 |
| Florida | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Texas | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

And I need it through iterations because In reality I have thousands of rows and dozens of different variables

Do you know what I can do to achieve this?

Comment: sounds like a job for groupby and count https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384532/get-statistics-for-each-group-such-as-count-mean-etc-using-pandas-groupby

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='State', columns = 'Age', values = 'Age', aggfunc = len)` will get you close to what you want.

Comment: What you're looking for is a crosstab operation. Try `df.groupby(['State', 'Age']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73060100/19123103) for explanation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72933069/19123103) on why `groupby` works.

Answer (score 2):

You want to group the students per State, showing the number of students of a specific age. This seems like an ideal use for a [pivot table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

Here's the pandas implementation (Note: I replace all NaN values with 0s).

```
df.pivot_table(index='State', columns = 'Age', values = 'Age', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `crosstab` function from pandas automatically aggregates the data and produces the expected result too.

```
pd.crosstab(index=df['State'], columns=df['Age'], dropna=True)
```

```
Age         9   10  11  12  13  14
State
----------------------------------                             
California   0   0   0   0   1   1
Colorado     0   1   2   3   2   0
Florida      0   1   1   0   0   0
Texas        1   1   1   1   0   0
```